How to perform a Global Sensitivity Analysis in R for a system of ODEs when state variables' initial values depend on parameter values?
I've set up a toy 2-compartment pharmacokinetic model to test different R packages for their capability to correctly perform GSA when there are state variables whose initial conditions (ICs) depend on parameter values assessed in the GSA.
I have not been able to get correct results in R (only in Python but the very complex non-toy model that I eventually want to apply this to is in R and I couldn't get the reticulate package to work) for the state variables with dependencies in their ICs.
Here is a runnable version of the toy model that does provide expected results:
# Clears environment before the run
rm(list=ls())

# Install and load necessary packages
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(deSolve, pksensi, sensitivity)


# Define the two-compartment model function
two_compartment_model_2CM <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    # Differential equations for the central compartment
    dCentral_2CM <- -(CL_2CM / Vc_2CM) * Central_2CM - (Q_2CM / Vc_2CM) * Central_2CM + 
      (Q_2CM / Vp_2CM) * Peripheral_2CM
    
    # Differential equations for the peripheral compartment
    dPeripheral_2CM <- (Q_2CM / Vc_2CM) * Central_2CM - (Q_2CM / Vp_2CM) * Peripheral_2CM
    
    # Calculate concentrations
    ConcCentral_2CM <- Central_2CM / Vc_2CM
    ConcPeripheral_2CM <- Peripheral_2CM / Vp_2CM
    
    # Return the list of derivatives and concentrations
    list(
      c(dCentral_2CM, dPeripheral_2CM),
      ConcCentral_2CM = ConcCentral_2CM,
      ConcPeripheral_2CM = ConcPeripheral_2CM
    )
  })
}



# Parameters for the 2-compartment model - units are hr and ml
two_compartment_pars_2CM <- c("CL_2CM", "Q_2CM", "Vc_2CM", "Vp_2CM")
two_compartment_BL_2CM <- c(CL_2CM = 0.31 * 1000 / 24, Q_2CM = 0.79 * 1000 / 24, Vc_2CM = 3.1 * 1000, Vp_2CM = 2.8 * 1000)

# dose
dose <- 400 

# Define initial state variables (Amounts only)
two_compartment_init_2CM <- c(
  Central_2CM    = dose,  # Initial amount in central compartment (mg)
  Peripheral_2CM = 0      # Initial amount in peripheral compartment (mg)
)

# Time points of interest
two_compartment_times_2CM <- c(seq(0.01, 100, by = 1), seq(100, 40*24, by = 12))

# Define lower and upper bounds for the parameters
two_compartment_binf_2CM <- two_compartment_BL_2CM * 0.85  # Lower bounds (85% of baseline)
two_compartment_bsup_2CM <- two_compartment_BL_2CM * 1.15  # Upper bounds (115% of baseline)

# Set up the distributions for the parameters (q should specify distribution types)
# sampled from a uniform distribution.
q <- c("qunif", "qunif", "qunif", "qunif")
q.arg <- list(
  list(min = two_compartment_binf_2CM["CL_2CM"], max = two_compartment_bsup_2CM["CL_2CM"]),
  list(min = two_compartment_binf_2CM["Q_2CM"], max = two_compartment_bsup_2CM["Q_2CM"]),
  list(min = two_compartment_binf_2CM["Vc_2CM"], max = two_compartment_bsup_2CM["Vc_2CM"]),
  list(min = two_compartment_binf_2CM["Vp_2CM"], max = two_compartment_bsup_2CM["Vp_2CM"])
)

# Generate parameter sets using Sobol sampling
set.seed(1234)
n_samples <- 1000
param_names <- two_compartment_pars_2CM
x <- rfast99(param_names, n = n_samples, q = q, q.arg = q.arg, replicate = 1)

# Perform ODE solving with solve_fun, including concentrations in outnames
out <- solve_fun(
  x = x,
  time = two_compartment_times_2CM,
  func = two_compartment_model_2CM,
  initState = two_compartment_init_2CM,
  outnames = c("Central_2CM", "Peripheral_2CM", "ConcCentral_2CM", "ConcPeripheral_2CM")
)

# Extract Sobol sensitivity indices for each parameter and plot them
par(mfrow = c(4, 1))  # Four plots vertically (Central S1, Peripheral S1, Central Conc S1, Peripheral Conc S1)

# Extract time points (from the first dimension of tSI)
time <- as.numeric(dimnames(out$tSI)[[1]])

# Set layout to 2x3 grid (3 plots on each row), with the 3rd plot on the top row containing the legend
par(mfrow = c(2, 3))

# Adjust margins for the plots (Bottom, Left, Top, Right margins)
par(mar = c(4, 4, 2, 2))

### First-order Sobol indices (S1) for central and peripheral compartments - parameters
S1_Central_CL <- out$tSI[, "CL_2CM", "Central_2CM"]
S1_Central_Q <- out$tSI[, "Q_2CM", "Central_2CM"]
S1_Central_Vc <- out$tSI[, "Vc_2CM", "Central_2CM"]
S1_Central_Vp <- out$tSI[, "Vp_2CM", "Central_2CM"]

S1_Peripheral_CL <- out$tSI[, "CL_2CM", "Peripheral_2CM"]
S1_Peripheral_Q <- out$tSI[, "Q_2CM", "Peripheral_2CM"]
S1_Peripheral_Vc <- out$tSI[, "Vc_2CM", "Peripheral_2CM"]
S1_Peripheral_Vp <- out$tSI[, "Vp_2CM", "Peripheral_2CM"]

# Plot Sobol sensitivity indices for the Central Compartment (S1 for parameters)
plot(time, S1_Central_CL, type = "l", col = "blue", lty = 1, ylim = c(0, 1),
     xlab = "Time (hours)", ylab = "S1 (First-Order Sobol Index)", 
     main = "Sobol Sensitivity - Central Compartment (Amount)")
lines(time, S1_Central_Q, col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(time, S1_Central_Vc, col = "green", lty = 3)
lines(time, S1_Central_Vp, col = "black", lty = 4)

# Plot Sobol sensitivity indices for the Peripheral Compartment (S1 for parameters)
plot(time, S1_Peripheral_CL, type = "l", col = "blue", lty = 1, ylim = c(0, 1),
     xlab = "Time (hours)", ylab = "S1 (First-Order Sobol Index)", 
     main = "Sobol Sensitivity - Peripheral Compartment (Amount)")
lines(time, S1_Peripheral_Q, col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(time, S1_Peripheral_Vc, col = "green", lty = 3)
lines(time, S1_Peripheral_Vp, col = "black", lty = 4)

# Create an empty plot in the top-right corner for the legend
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))  # No margins for the legend plot
plot.new()

# Add the legend in the empty third plot (top-right)
legend("center", legend = c("CL_2CM", "Q_2CM", "Vc_2CM", "Vp_2CM"), 
       col = c("blue", "red", "green", "black"), lty = 1:4, lwd = 2, cex = 1.2)

### First-order Sobol indices (S1) for concentrations in central and peripheral compartments
S1_Conc_Central_CL <- out$tSI[, "CL_2CM", "ConcCentral_2CM"]
S1_Conc_Central_Q <- out$tSI[, "Q_2CM", "ConcCentral_2CM"]
S1_Conc_Central_Vc <- out$tSI[, "Vc_2CM", "ConcCentral_2CM"]
S1_Conc_Central_Vp <- out$tSI[, "Vp_2CM", "ConcCentral_2CM"]

S1_Conc_Peripheral_CL <- out$tSI[, "CL_2CM", "ConcPeripheral_2CM"]
S1_Conc_Peripheral_Q <- out$tSI[, "Q_2CM", "ConcPeripheral_2CM"]
S1_Conc_Peripheral_Vc <- out$tSI[, "Vc_2CM", "ConcPeripheral_2CM"]
S1_Conc_Peripheral_Vp <- out$tSI[, "Vp_2CM", "ConcPeripheral_2CM"]

# Reset margins for the bottom row
par(mar = c(4, 4, 2, 2))  # Reset margins for the bottom plots

# Plot Sobol sensitivity indices for the Concentration in the Central Compartment (S1 for all parameters)
plot(time, S1_Conc_Central_CL, type = "l", col = "blue", lty = 1, ylim = c(0, 1),
     xlab = "Time (hours)", ylab = "S1 (First-Order Sobol Index)", 
     main = "Sobol Sensitivity - Central Compartment (Concentration)")
lines(time, S1_Conc_Central_Q, col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(time, S1_Conc_Central_Vc, col = "green", lty = 3)
lines(time, S1_Conc_Central_Vp, col = "black", lty = 4)

# Plot Sobol sensitivity indices for the Concentration in the Peripheral Compartment (S1 for all parameters)
plot(time, S1_Conc_Peripheral_CL, type = "l", col = "blue", lty = 1, ylim = c(0, 1),
     xlab = "Time (hours)", ylab = "S1 (First-Order Sobol Index)", 
     main = "Sobol Sensitivity - Peripheral Compartment (Concentration)")
lines(time, S1_Conc_Peripheral_Q, col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(time, S1_Conc_Peripheral_Vc, col = "green", lty = 3)
lines(time, S1_Conc_Peripheral_Vp, col = "black", lty = 4)

# Create an empty panel in the bottom-right (this plot will remain empty)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot.new()

However, to have a toy model that is representative of the complex model that I am looking to apply the GSA to afterwards, I'd have to have the problem set up such that the ConcPeripheral_2CM and ConcCentral_2CM are also stated as differential equations. Then the IC for ConcCentral_2CM would depend on dose and on the parameter Vc_2CM:
# Define the two-compartment model function with concentration differentials
two_compartment_model_2CM <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    # Differential equations for the central compartment
    dCentral_2CM <- -(CL_2CM / Vc_2CM) * Central_2CM - (Q_2CM / Vc_2CM) * Central_2CM + 
      (Q_2CM / Vp_2CM) * Peripheral_2CM
    
    # Differential equations for the peripheral compartment
    dPeripheral_2CM <- (Q_2CM / Vc_2CM) * Central_2CM - (Q_2CM / Vp_2CM) * Peripheral_2CM
    
    # Differential equations for concentrations
    dConcCentral_2CM <- dCentral_2CM / Vc_2CM
    dConcPeripheral_2CM <- dPeripheral_2CM / Vp_2CM
    
    # Return the list of derivatives and concentrations
    return(list(c(dCentral_2CM, dPeripheral_2CM, dConcCentral_2CM, dConcPeripheral_2CM)))
  })
}

Then the ICs should be something like:
  two_compartment_init_2CM <- c(
    Central_2CM = dose,
    Peripheral_2CM = 0,
    ConcCentral_2CM = dose / PLACEHOLDER_CONTAINING_APPROPRIATE_VALUE_OF_Vc_2CM,
    ConcPeripheral_2CM = 0
  )

But this is the part I cannot get to work, unfortunately. The results should be equivalent to the above code's results but I get incorrect results for the GSA for ConcPeripheral_2CM.
Until I have this figured out, I cannot apply this to my more complex model with much more complex parameter dependencies. I would be super helpful for any advice on how to get the appropriate results with the setup as in the second code block. Whether the GSA uses the Sobol method or the Morris Elementary method or even another one is not important. What is important is that I want to understand the sensitivity over time.
Thanks a lot in advance!!
The first code block above is one thing I tried to understand what the expected results are. It gives:
Results to be expected; performed using formulation of problem without parameter-dependence in the ICs
for a system of ODEs yielding:
Time profiles for state variables involved in the GSA (mainly FYI, not necessary to solve the problem)
Any other way I have tried to reformulate the problem as in the 2nd / 3rd code block above has yielded incorrect results for ConcPeripheral_2CM:
Initial conditions depending on a parameter that is varied during the GSA yield incorrect results for ConcPeripheral_2CM
I have tried using odemorris and odesobol from the ODEsensitivity package as well as pksensi together with the sensitivity package and get the same results with either of them.

Welcome to StackOverflow! We appreciate your question, but to increase the likelihood of getting an answer, I would recommend reducing the question to its essential core. For example, reduce and simplify the plotting stuff and simplify your model. Instead of your specialized case study, use something more abstract and theoretical, e.g. from a textbook, that more people can understand. You can find instructions in How to make a great R reproducible example.
